# Gradle - how to run ant task with "-" in name

Tags: ant, gradle, cobertura

I want to use cobertura in my gradle build so I created task in this way:

```
ant.typedef(resource: 'tasks.properties', classpath:configurations.cobertura.asPath)
```

And now I want to run `cobertura-instrument`. The problem is that I don't know how to run this task because `ant.cobertura-instrument(...)` won't work. Is there some other way to run it? For example something like this `ant.tasks['cobertura-instrument'](...)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use the task like this `ant."cobertura-instrument"(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem solved**

Ant task name can be changed using `name` argument. For `cobertura-instrument` it looks like this:

```
ant.typedef(classname:'net.sourceforge.cobertura.ant.InstrumentTask', name:'coberturaInstrument', classpath:configurations.cobertura.asPath)
```

so task can be usd in this way:

```
ant.coberturaInstrument(...)
```

Comment: You can also use the task like this `ant."cobertura-instrument"(...)`.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin! I think that your answer is better because it doesn't require to rename task. Add this as an answer if you can.

Comment: BTW: I saw you were trying to use the Cobertura Ant tasks. Did you try out the [Cobertura Gradle plugin](https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-cobertura-plugin)?

Comment: No i didn't. I'll try it. Thanks again!