# Invoke Ant from Gradle with unfortunate tag name

Tags: gradle, groovy, ant

I'm trying to invoke yGuard Ant task from Gradle:

```
ant.taskdef(name:'yguard', classname:'com.yworks.yguard.YGuardTask', classpath: '../yguard/yguard-2.9.2.jar;../yguard/retroguard-2.9.2.jar;../yguard/guava-28.1-android.jar;../yguard/asm-7.2.jar')
ant.yguard {
    inoutpair(in: 'in.jar', out: 'out.jar')
    attribute(name:'Deprecated, SourceFile, LineNumberTable, LocalVariableTable, LocalVariableTypeTable')
    rename(mainclass:"com.....z.Z",logfile:"obfuscation.log",replaceClassNameStrings:"true") {
        keep {
            class(implements:"java.io.Serializable",classes:"private",methods:"private",fields:"private") {
                patternset {
                    include name:"org.**.*"
                    include name:"com.google.**.*"
                    include name:"com.sun.**.*"
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm quite used to invoke Ant from Gradle, but here I'm stuck on the tag name which is named `<class .../>`. Of course Groovy confused with the getClass() method.

I've tried the following alternative (as suggested here: [Gradle - how to run ant task with "-" in name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338450/gradle-how-to-run-ant-task-with-in-name)):
`ant.class` => same
`ant."class"` => don't know what it does, but doesn't work :)
But it is still confusing with getClass() method I think

of course, there is the following solution:

- use `ant.importBuild` instead, to write XML instead of groovy scripts, but it would be too easy ;) And I'd would really like to stay in groovy/gradle DSL if possible
- I could use yGuard gradle plugin instead, but I encountered problems

The example with yGuard is just an example. I would really love to understand which mechanism is used underneath, and how to enforce the behavior I want (Groovy is so powerful, I'm pretty sure, there is a way)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, in the end:

`ant.class` AND `ant."class"` is working. I hope the complete sample can help someone else to translate his ant script to Gradle!

```
    ant.taskdef(name:'yguard', classname:'com.yworks.yguard.YGuardTask', classpath: '../yguard/yguard-2.9.2.jar;../yguard/retroguard-2.9.2.jar;../yguard/guava-28.1-android.jar;../yguard/asm-7.2.jar')
    ant.yguard {
        inoutpair(in: 'in.jar', out: 'out.jar')
        attribute(name:'Deprecated, SourceFile, LineNumberTable, LocalVariableTable, LocalVariableTypeTable')
        rename(mainclass:"com.....z.Z",logfile:"obfuscation.log",replaceClassNameStrings:"true") {
            keep {
                ant.class(classes:"private",methods:"private",fields:"private") {
                    patternset {
                        include name:"org.**.*"
                        include name:"com.google.**.*"
                        include name:"com.sun.**.*"
                        // ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

original ant script:

```
    <taskdef name="yguard" classname="com.yworks.yguard.YGuardTask" classpath="yguard/yguard-2.9.2.jar;yguard/retroguard-2.9.2.jar;yguard/guava-28.1-android.jar;yguard/asm-7.2.jar" />
            <yguard>
                <inoutpair in="in.jar" out="out.jar"/>
    
                <!-- Keep all of the attributes for debugging, e.g. -->
                <attribute name="Deprecated, SourceFile, LineNumberTable, LocalVariableTable, LocalVariableTypeTable" />
    
                <rename mainclass="com.....z.Z" logfile="obfuscation.log" replaceClassNameStrings="true">
                    <keep>
                        <class classes="private" methods="private" fields="private">
                            <patternset>
                                <include name="org.**.*" />
                                <include name="com.google.**.*" />
                                <include name="com.sun.**.*" />
                                <include name="com.thoughtworks.**.*" />
                                <!-- ... -->
                            </patternset>
                        </class>
                    </keep>
                </rename>
            </yguard>
```

the machinery behind all this still hold though ;-) I had a look into DefaultAntBuilder source code, but not much help.